# Angular - Jasmine can real XHR be executed?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I do not want to have the $http mocked. Main reason is that I am writing some integration tests so I want to have all AJAX requests executed. Currently in my tests none gets triggered.
Any suggestion is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular mocks provide the mocked $httpBackend when you are using Jasmine tests, but the actual $httpBackend still exists. You just need to tell the provider to use the original when you inject the service. It will look something like this in your test:

```
var original_http_backend = null; 
angular.module('ng').config(['$httpBackendProvider', function($httpBackendProvider) {
     original_http_backend = $httpBackendProvider;
}]);

beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
     $provide.provider('$httpBackend', original_http_backend)
}));
```

It's also worth pointing out that this approach, in general, is a BAD way to test your front end code. This is because it adds a backend dependency, so you cannot isolate your front end behavior. It is preferred to mock out the response and test with that.

I did end up using this feature though, since our mock responses were developed on the back end for testing there, and I didn't want to repeat the objects. This method allowed me to use them.

Comment: I have used a different trick until now, but your answer will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to test async operations, then you can use [Jasmine Async Support](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support). It basically consists in creating blocks of `runs()` alongside with `waitsFor`. A simple example:

```js
var $http, returned;

it('should evaluate real XHR request', function() {
  // this will probably reside in your controller
  $http.$get('/foo.json').success(function(data) { returned = data; });

  waitsFor(function() {
    return !!returned;
  }, 'The $http didnt resolved in 1 second', 1000);

  runs(function() {
    expect(returned).toBe('The value you expect to be returned');
  });
});
```

Each `runs` block will run in the specified order, and when a `waitsFor` happens, the runs block will wait until the previous `waitsFor` resolve to `true` to run.

Comment: I have tried this also. My Issues is that the actual http request is not executed at all. If I am using JQuery for example in a Jasmine test to make an http request all works just fine. It might be something related to angular I assume.